# Datagridview сортировка

Tags: c#, winforms

Использую winForms. Проблема такая: вывожу в datagridview данные, у некоторых значений меняю цвет фона ячейки:

```
 datagridview .Rows[е].Cells[о].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

Но стоит нажать на заголовок колонки, что вызывает сортировку по убыванию/возрастанию, сразу же слетают все цвета. Как сделать привязку цвета к значению или как поймать событие сортировки?

Answer (score 1):

Пример в [документации](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.aspx) подписывается на `CellFormatting` и переприменяет модификацию стилей.